# Load next array item in PHP quiz

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a small PHP quiz and I have a `Multidimensional Array` set up (which houses my question titles and questions), I then use `rand_array` to chose one of the arrays and display it into my page. After it has been displayed I use `unset($row);` to remove it from my `Multidimensional Array` so that the same question is never shown twice.

There are three buttons (for the three answers) and when that is clicked it will give 0, 10 or 20 points to the user. I have used this to get the points back:

`if (isset($_POST["Answer1"])){

        $points = $points + 20;

        initialQuestions();

}`

I run `initialQuestions();` again to get the next question but this obviously resets my entire array, how do I make it skip to the next question with the previous item removed from the array eventually leading it to be a blank array?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the script that unsets the value?

Comment: What stops you from storing the answered questions in the session, then exclude them? Or the other way round - store the possible questions in the sesssion?

Comment: Where is the array stored?

Comment: Dainis - This is my function - http://pastebin.com/A86NeLWr  

@EugenRieck I can store the answered questions in a session, which is my next step, but I cannot get the next question to load without it resetting the array  

Alepac -  I have tried storing my array outside and inside my function, neither change the outcome

Answer (score 0):

use array splice instead of unset cause the vallue gets nulled but the key remains

Answer (score 0):

initialQuestions()? And where is Your array?
use initialQuestions($question_array) and return array without current question;

Something like this

```
$questions = array('your array');
function initialQuestions($questions) {
//get some question
//remove it from array
return $questions;//return this array
}
```

then

```
if (isset($_POST["Answer1"])){ $points = $points + 20; $questions = initialQuestions($questions);
```

or globalize $questions array

```
function initialQuestions() {
global $questions;
//get some question
//remove it from array
}
```

But best for me is using $_SESSION to store Your $question array.

Comment: The first solution has not seemed to work in my script, it will load the next question but it does not remove another question from my array, only the array removed the first time which is the problem. You can see this here - http://pastebin.com/km6Zkar8 . I will try to do it using $_SESSION

Answer (score -1):

you can just randomly pull a question from the all_question array, and save this 'used' question into Session, then doesn't matter what you do in the POST back, the next time when you pull a 'next' question from all_question, you just check it see if it's already stored in the 'used' Session, if so, pull again, if not, you got what you want.

```
<?php
session_start();

$all_question = array(
    //put all your question here...
);

//pull a question out
$new_question = pull_question( $all_question );

//save this question to the 'used' session
$_SESSION['used_question'][] = $new_question;

?>
```